# jquery - change button's text on click works only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many buttons that have same class but different id on each. The following html button is added beside each $data element.

```
<button name="toHomepageButton" id = "<?php echo $data->id ?>" class="frontpage"><?php if ($data->isChecked == 1) echo "Remove from homepage"; else echo "Promote to homepage" ; ?> </button>
```

Now I want to change individual button's text based on if it is clicked. i.e. if a button is clicked and it has text "Promote to homepage", it's text should change to "Remove from homepage" and vice versa. I used the following jquery code to do so.

```
$('.frontpage').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    $("#"+id).html($("#"+id).html() == "Promote to homepage" ? "Remove from homepage" : "Promote to homepage");
});
```

Now this code works but **only on second click**. i.e. when I click a promote to homepage button, it's text won't change but if I click it again, the text changes. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: When rendering the page, has the button `id` the correct value? Because, if I try in plain HTML (removing the PHP code), your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/aforni/26z3z0xo/

Comment: Does your page going to other page, mean does button link to other page and onclick page is refreshing?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to try it on jsfiddle. The problem was the extra space as stated by @DGS

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you resolved your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you might be adding in extra spacing when you echo out from PHP

Try

```
<button name="toHomepageButton" id = "<?php echo $data->id ?>" class="frontpage"><?php if ($data->isChecked == 1) echo "Remove from homepage"; else echo "Promote to homepage" ; ?></button>
```

Notice the removed space after the echo. This means that `$("#"+id).html() == "Promote to homepage"` Will never never true however `$("#"+id).html() == "Promote to homepage "` Would be

Comment: That's the main issue. For the first time it is setting `Promote to homepage` from the else part. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot... The problem was indeed the extra spacing. Such a stupid mistake!!

Answer (score 7):

In this case you should use `text()` instead of `html()` as it has simple text. 
Take care of the spaces. Use `$.trim` before comparing the values.
Try with -

```
$('.frontpage').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = ($.trim($this.text()) == "Promote to homepage") ? "Remove from homepage" : "Promote to homepage";
    $this.text(text);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g3yqvwog/4/)

Comment: Doesn't explain OP's behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes. The issue is with the `space`.

Comment: @Andrea Yes it works. If there is no `html` then why use `html()`? `text()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap all your functions on dom ready event.

```
$(function () {
    $('.frontpage').on('click', function () {
        var curTxt = $(this).text() == "Promote to homepage" ? "Remove from homepage" : "Promote to homepage";
        $(this).text(curTxt)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you.

```
$('.frontpage').on('click', function() {

    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Promote to homepage') {
        $(this).text('Remove from homepage');
    }

    else if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Remove from homepage') {
        $(this).text('Promote to homepage');        
    }
});
```